# .htaccess / PHP URL rewrite not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a simple php form that uses action="index.php", so when the form is submitted I get this:
dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/index.php

But I would like it to display as:
dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/results/

This is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/index.php? dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/results/ [NC,L]
```

I am new to URL rewriting so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your .htaccess to remove `index.php` from your URL:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flipping it around. You're rule says if you match `dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/index.php` then send it to `dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/results/` ... but you want it the other way around. You should also leave off the domain and only include the path.

```
RewriteRule ^apps/myapp/r4/results/$ /apps/myapp/r4/index.php [L]
```

Here we look for a request for `/apps/myapp/r4/results/` and send it to `/apps/myapp/r4/index.php` without a redirect. If you include a domain on where you want to send the request, even if it's the same domain, it will perform a redirect.

Comment: No, I need the URL to display as 'dev.mysite.net/apps/myapp/r4/results/'. It currently shows ..r4/index.php, which I do not want.

Comment: http://searchfriendlyurls.com/ Go put in your URL, the old path, and the new path and see what it gives you.